# Insert data using WCF Rest based service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I want to inser data using my REST based service. While I am consuming the service, my service is not hit. It shows 400 Error when I use Network Icon on IE. My code is as below:-

```
//IService1.cs       
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        [OperationContract]
        void AddEmployee(string EmpName, int Salary, string Dept);

//Service1.svc.cs
        public void AddEmployee(string EmpName, int Salary, string Dept)
        {
            //Employee emp = new Employee();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Emp (sEmpName,iSalary,sDept) Values('" + EmpName + "','" + Salary + "','" + Dept + "') ", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Consuming Service on my aspx page

```
       function insertEmployeeWCF() {
            var Name = $('#txt2').val();
            var Salary = $('#txt3').val();
            var Department = $('#txt4').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:1626/Service1.svc/AddEmployee",
                //data: "{}",
                data: "{'EmpName':'" + Name + "','Salary':'" + Salary + "','Dept':'" + Department + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var employee = response.d;
                    $('#<%=lbl5.ClientID%>').html("Value successfully inserted")

                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: You might add your WCF configuration File.  There has to be some additions to that in order to make WCF restful.

Comment: I have made those additions, and one of my WCF function is executing perfectly